# Get JAX-RS (Resteasy) @Path annotation value from ClientRequestContext/ClientRequestFilter/similar when intercepted

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy, opentracing

Question: How can we obtain the @Path value for the proxied resource interface from a JAX-RS interceptor/filter?

Detail:
When a HTTP request comes through a service using JAX-RS it is matched using an annotated Resource java interface

```
public interface UserClient
{
    @GET
    @Path("/user/{id}")
    User getUser(@PathParam("id") UUID id);
}
```

Within JAX-RS is also a chain-of-responsibility pattern of intercepters and filters. Currently we use a filter (ClientRequestFilter) to record our network calls in our intra-service tracing platform.

We have the opportunity to give our traces a display name, and this is grouped/indexed by the tracing platform. I would like to use the rest endpoint as a name, however if using @Path variables this becomes part of the URI, and as such your IDs (in the above example) also get included, and as such instead of your tracing platform grouping calls together like `/user/{userId}` with a single name, you end up with many names `/user/1`, `/user/2`, `/user/n`.

Is there any part of the JAX-RS framework where you can intercept http calls and you have access to the Resource proxy interface you have matched for that http call? Or some other way to determine the pattern that a http call was matched to?

Comment: The answer would be completely dependent on which jax-rs implementation you're using. You might want to add that in the title and it's tag on the question.

Comment: Quite right, thank you.

Comment: Can you just put the class as a property using `WebTarget.property()` method? Then in the filter, just use context.getProperty().

Comment: @PaulSamsotha thanks for the suggestion - this would only give class rather than method resolution, but I may try it as a fallback.

Comment: You can inject the `UriInfo` and parse that. In your implementation it would be something like `@Context UriInfo uriInfo`.

Comment: Thanks @JamesR.Perkins - I have since tried this with the ResourceInfo object and whlist it is injected, resourceInfo.getResourceMethod() returns null always. I'll try UriInfo to see what it contains.

Answer (score 1):

After some different approaches, the following seems to work. I can't confirm its reliability under all circumstances, but so far it does the job.

```
Optional.of(clientRequestContext)
                .filter(ClientRequestContextImpl.class::isInstance)
                .map(ClientRequestContextImpl.class::cast)
                .map(ClientRequestContextImpl::getInvocation)
                .map(ClientInvocation::getClientInvoker)
                .map(ClientInvoker::getMethod)
                .map(method -> method.getAnnotation(Path.class))
                .map(Path::value)
                .orElseThrow();
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this answer. Did you find another more "reliable" way to do so ? I am experiencing the same issue. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71512013/how-to-get-resteasy-client-annotation-in-clientrequestfilter

Comment: Hi @mcanzerini - we left the code with the above and didn't have any problems with it that I know of.